# Doctrine: always tells me the database isn't in sync after using two custom mapping types

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've created two [custom mapping types](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html): one for a [Money value object](https://github.com/Aerendir/PHPValueObjects/blob/master/src/Money/Persistence/MoneyType.php) and one for an [Email value object](https://github.com/Aerendir/PHPValueObjects/blob/master/src/Email/Persistence/EmailType.php)

Now, each time I run `app/console doctrine:schema:validate` Doctrine tells me the database is not in sync.

Dumping the `sql` with `app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` it wants each time to update the same fields in the same way:

```
ALTER TABLE invoices CHANGE total total VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE subscriptions CHANGE next_payment_amount next_payment_amount VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE stripe_charges CHANGE amount amount VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, CHANGE receipt_email receipt_email VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE stripe_customers CHANGE email email VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
```

**Each time it tries to update these tables setting them in the exact same state they already are. Is a fault of mine or is a Doctrine's one?**

Here the code for the two types: [`MoneyType`](https://github.com/Aerendir/PHPValueObjects/blob/master/src/Money/Persistence/MoneyType.php) and [`EmailType`](https://github.com/Aerendir/PHPValueObjects/blob/master/src/Email/Persistence/EmailType.php).

GitHub/Doctrine Issue [here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6077).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine is seeing each of the columns on your database as strings but thinking you want them to be money/email so it's deciding that you need to migrate each time.

The way to sort this is by adding the `requiresSQLCommentHint` so that it adds some text in your column comment to show that it actually is the correct customer type. You do this by just adding..

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return true;
}
```

.. to your custom types and Doctrine will handle the rest.